# How to use closure in a recursive function without losing scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, scope, closures

- **tem.jqw.Callback** object contains an executable function, a CSS selector. and a looping delay.
- **tem.jqw.wait** waits for jQuery to be loaded and then goes through an array of **tem.jqw.Callback** objects and executes their functions after having found an element with the CSS selector passed in.

The problem I am having is in the **run** function within the **tem.jqw.Callback** object. When the run function is called the first time, if the element exists, everything is fine and the executable function runs OK. However, if the element does not yet exist, and we need to loop, the function loses scope after **setTimeout(this.run, 100)** executes once. For example, when the run function is executing the second time, this.selector or this.fn become undefined. How can I work around this without using global variables? Thanks in advance.

```js
if (typeof tem !== "object") {
  tem = {};
}

tem.jqw = {};
tem.jqw.retries = 0;
tem.jqw.maxRetries = 100;
tem.jqw.delay = 100;
tem.jqw.callbacks = [];

tem.jqw.Callback = function (fn, selector, delay) {
  this.fn = fn;
  this.selector = (typeof selector === "string" && selector.length > 0) ? selector : document;
  this.delay = (typeof delay === "number" && delay > 0 && delay < 1000) ? delay : 100;

  this.retries = 0;
  this.maxRetries = 100;

  this.start = function () {
    this.run();
  };

  this.run = function () {
    if (jQuery(this.selector).length > 0) {
      console.log("[OPDEBUG] tem.jqw.Callback.run says: " + this.selector.toString() + " is ready. Executing callback function...");
      this.fn();
    } else {
      this.retries++;
      console.log("[OPDEBUG] tem.jqw.Callback.run says: typeof this.selector " + typeof this.selector);
      console.log("[OPDEBUG] tem.jqw.Callback.run says: Waiting for " + this.selector.toString() + "...");
      if (this.retries < this.maxRetries) {
        setTimeout(this.run, 100);
      }
    }
  };
};

tem.jqw.wait = function () {
  if (typeof jQuery === "function") {
    console.log("[OPDEBUG] tem.jqw.wait says: jQuery is ready.");
    for (var i = 0; i < tem.jqw.callbacks.length; i++) {
      if (typeof tem.jqw.callbacks[i] === "object" && typeof tem.jqw.callbacks[i].start === "function") {
        console.log("[OPDEBUG] tem.jqw.wait says: Executing callback function " + (i + 1) + "...");
        tem.jqw.callbacks[i].start();
      }
    }
  } else {
    tem.jqw.retries++;
    console.log("[OPDEBUG] tem.jqw.wait says: " + "Waiting for jQuery " + tem.jqw.retries + "...");
    if (tem.jqw.retries < tem.jqw.maxRetries) {
      setTimeout(tem.jqw.wait, tem.jqw.delay);
    }
  }
};

tem.jqw.callbacks.push(new tem.jqw.Callback(function () {
  jQuery('.hero-inner:first a').css('background-image', 'url("https://www.thedogs.co.nz/Files/PhotoFinishImages/11298_89160.jpg")')
}, ".hero-inner:first"));
tem.jqw.callbacks.push(new tem.jqw.Callback(function () {
  jQuery('.RR-placeholder ul li:first').hide();
}, ".RR-placeholder ul li:first"));
tem.jqw.wait();
```

Comment: `setTimeout(this.run.bind( this ), 100)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use bind to set this

change `this.run()` to

```
this.run.bind(this)
```

Its better to assign **this** to another variable eg)

```
var self = this;
```

and then pass around self for better readability

Comment: this.run.bind(this) works!

Where do I do: var self = this? Would that be the first thing to do in the run function?

And then, would I need to do: setTimeout(self.run, 100)?

Thanks!

Comment: I prefer a name describing the object rather than *self*, which is no more descriptive than *this* or *that*. Maybe `callback = this`.